# How kubernetes service work in case of Database (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, database-design, kubernetes

I'm new to k8 and i would like to create a mysql k8 service.

So my question is, if i create a k8 service with multiple pods which has mysql database, how the data will be inserted and also how fetch request processed?

- will all the records will be synchronized to all pods?
- while fetching will it collect records from all pods?

after little bit of googling i came to know that some load balancing kinda thing is happening in background...so suppose if a record is saved to mysql database which is in **pod1** and for the http get request will to go for **pod2** for get the record?

so how something like this will workout?

[image]

Comment: Kubernetes doesn’t really know about any of this.  If you have multiple MySQL pods with a service in front of them, it will route requests to one of them, and it’s up to the database to figure it out from there.  (Always “Kubernetes” or “k8s”, ending with an “s”.)

Comment: ok thanks @DavidMaze ...i have heard about mongodb sharding..so based on that if k8s create a new pod from scaling criteria how its gonna work?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) for this purpose. Statefulsets include the ability to specify a pod to reach through the service using the internal DNS. An example of this using a statefulset called mysql being exposed using a service called mysql in the default namesapce, you can reach a specific pod (such as the master for writes) using mysql-0.mysql.default.svc.cluster.local

There is actually a [statefulset example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/) that uses mysql specifically on kubernetes.io. This example leverages the properties of the statefulset to ensure that pod-0 will be your master so you can reliably send writes to it and send read requests to one of the read-only servers.